# jQuery UI sortable table handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having some difficults with sortable option handle.

When I use:

```
$("table tr").sortable().disableSelection();
```

There is no problem.

If I add the handle option then the sortable stops working:

```
$("table tr").sortable({
    handle: "td:eq(0)"
}).disableSelection();
```

The links:

http://jsfiddle.net/22C2n/

http://jsfiddle.net/22C2n/1/

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Wrap your `<tr>`'s in a `<tbody>` and change your code to:

```
$("table tbody").sortable({
    handle: 'td:first'
}).disableSelection();
```

You specify the container that contains the elements you want to be sortable not the actual elements...

Comment: Perfect!!!! Its start the sorting from table 'FIRST' column, so you can select column text easily. Don't forget to remove .disableSelection() option.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass an element: http://jsfiddle.net/22C2n/5/

```
$("table tr").sortable({
    handle: $("td:eq(0)")
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the code does not work, at leas at chrome.

Comment: Yes, i was trying with 6A. But still, 1B and 1C (also 1A after you drop it) are moved to the right.Also it is not sorting

Answer (score 0):

Setting the handle to `td:eq(0)` makes only the first table cell sortable, all the rest of the cells are not. Try adding a `span` inside the `td` and use it as the handle ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/22C2n/6/)).

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span>&bull;</span>1A</td>
        <td>1B</td>
        <td>1C</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Script

```
$("table tr").sortable({
    handle: "span"
}).disableSelection();
```